# Run npm command prebuild Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, pre-build-event

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to create a new Core RazorPage application.
I need to run the following commands inside my WWWRoot folder

```
npm install
npm run build
```

I tried to add the following commands inside my pre-build script

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npm i $(ProjectDir)wwwroot" />
  </Target>
```

but nothing happen and i am getting the folowing warning

> npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'E:\Dev\package.json'

it seems that it completely ignores the wwwroot
in the path

Comment: Ensure dependencies described correctly on `package.json`

Answer (score 8):

VS19 doesn't like not having the package.json at the root of the project.  I was able to add a package.json at the root of the project, and add the script:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cd wwwroot && npm i && npm run build"
  },
```

the `node_modules` folder was then created in the `wwwroot` folder and the `npm run build` command was run inside the child folder.  I would also recommend the Extension "NpmTaskRunner" (https://github.com/madskristensen/NpmTaskRunner).  You can then bind the root build script to the VS Build event.

Answer (score 3):

After moving an ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET Core Application I had, almost, the same problem with npm.
If I created the package.json file inside a Project I end up with:

- npm installing a lot of packages
- npm command does not run in Package Manager Console
- I would need package.json (and node_modules directory) inside other Web Application in the same Solution

After struggling for a while I followed a different approach, and it is working up to now:

- Create a package.json (and node_modules) at the Solution level
- Install dependencies here
- Copy path you need to **wwwroot** using **Gulp**
- Create an EMPTY package.json at the Project Level
- Install **del** and **gulp** globally (DEV dependencies)
- Create a symlink for **del** and **gulp** at project level

There is a detailed description of this approach (compared to the usual) at the link below:

[A better way to use Visual Studio with npm (and Gulp)](https://easylob.wordpress.com/2019/12/26/a-better-way-to-use-visual-studio-with-npm-and-gulp/)

Please let me now if this works for your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.bat` file and run it in Debug mode

open [build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022) and add this to pre-build events

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
   call "$(ProjectDir)prebuild.bat"
)
```

then open up prebuild.bat file and add yarn or npm command like this

```
cd .. 
call yarn install 

cd project1
call yarn install 
call yarn build 
cd .. 

cd project2
call yarn install 
call yarn build 
cd .. 

cd project3 
call yarn install 
call yarn build 
cd ..

cd project4
call yarn install 
call yarn build 
cd ..
```

And for sure you can replace calling the `.bat` file with its content