# `npm run serve` does not fail on errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, lint

I have a Vue view, somethink like:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { firstItem } from "@/path/to/my/file";

onMounted(async () => {
  let f1 = getFirstItem();
  let f2 = getSecondItem();
});
```

As you can see, there is an Import for `firstItem`, but I forgot to add an import for `secondItem`.

My issue - Why such a code is passing `npm run serve` successfully? In fact, the website does not work (as expeted).
How can I make `npm run serve` to fail instead of this confusing scenario that I was sure everything is OK with my code, and was not aware to this error?

By The Way, `npm run lint` **DO** show this error, but I do not remember to run `npm run lint` bfore every `npm run serve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved the issue by editing package.json file, and adding `lint` call on each `serve`:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service lint && vue-cli-service serve", ...
```

This solution is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58070493/5699936

Answer (score 1):

It is a runtime error, not a compile time error.  If you run a type checker before you run `npm run serve`, the command will fail.

You can also change your `typescript` config settings to report an error.

Somewhere in your typescript settings, you are allowing undeclared global functions, or have disabled the type checking.

Sometimes this happens when the `global` object is overriden as type `any`.

Comment: Cannot find any related config setting.